# Continuity of maps and quotient spaces

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, quotient-spaces

Let $q:X\rightarrow Y$ be a continuous surjective map

$q:X \rightarrow Y$ is a quotient map $\iff$ $q$ takes saturated open subsets to open subsets.

My attempt:

Let $q:X \rightarrow Y$ be a continuous surjective quotient map. This means $Y$ is equipped with the quotient topology. So, if $U\subseteq$ $X$ is a saturated open subset of $X$, $U=q^{-1}(q(U))$. Since $q(U)$ is a subset of $Y$, it is open in Y, by definition of the quotient topology.

For the converse, suppose $q$ takes saturated open subsets to open subsets. Let $\tau_Y$ be the topology on $Y$ and $\tau'_Y$ the quotient topology induced by $q$, I must show that the two topologies are equal. If $A\in \tau_Y$ then since $q$ is continuous, $q^{-1}(A)$ is open in $X$, hence $A\in \tau'_Y$. If $V\in \tau'_Y$ then since $q^{-1}(V)$ is open in $X$. By assumption, $V$ is open ($\tau_Y)$ in $Y$.

Is my attempt correct? (Please answer this question)

Comment: What is your definition of "saturated"?

Comment: @Tri second line of the first paragraph of the proof has the definition. Applied to $U$. Anything equivalent to something in $U$ is already in $U$( in terms of the equivalence relation induced by $q$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the last paragraph is wrong, as you do not even use the assumption on saturated open sets.

Better: let $O$ be a subset of $Y$ such that $O'=q^{-1}[O]$ is open in $X$. We need to show that $O$ is open in $Y$ to have that $q$ is a quotient map. (we already have the continuity).

Note that $O'$ is saturated (the inverse image of any set under $q$ always is, exercise!) and so by assumption $q[O']$ is open. By surjectiveness however, $q[O']=O$ and we are thus done.

Comment: Out of curiosity, which parts of the last paragraph are wrong? All of it?

Comment: @topologicalmagician you didn’t use the assumption like I said.

Comment: If $V\in \tau'_Y$ then since $q^{-1}(V)$ is open in $X$. By assumption, $V$ is open ($\tau_Y)$ in $Y$. What I meant here is that $q^{-1}(V)=B$ for some subset $B$ of $X$, so $B$ is saturated, hence $q(B)=V$ which is open in $Y$ by assumption ,no? Moreover, Is the method of showing that the two topologies are equal correct?

Comment: @topologicalmagician you don’t have to show the topologies are equal. That’s making it needlessly difficult.

Comment: @topologicalmagician you don't say that $V$ is saturated explicitly , while you want to use the assumption on the right.